# Core Data & NSFetchedResultsController: ignoring fields in controllerDidChangeContent

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a background thread that performs background updates, sets/overwrites fields on several kinds of NSManagedObjects. All subclasses include a lastModified attribute which always gets updated when being processed by the background task.

My problem is that when I do this, all entities that are hit by the background thread will also trigger controllerWillChangeContent/controllerDidChangeContent. Even if nothing really changed.

- If I hit a setter (for example with an NSString but the contents didn't actually change, will it still trigger an update or is CoreDate clever enough to ignore this?
- Is it possible to somehow mark an attribute to not be included when notifying changes to resultsControllers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `setPrimitiveValue:forKey:` to change a NSManagedObject without sending any KVO notifications (which trigger the nsfetchedresultscontroller to update)

for example

```
[self setPrimitiveValue:[NSDate date] forKey:@"lastModified"]
```

You can read more about these here
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdAccessorMethods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002154-SW5

Comment: I tried this, but it seems `setPrimitiveValue` also prevents the value from being persisted?

Comment: I really mean that resultsControllers aren't being notified of changes in lastModified, or perhaps that there's a way of distinguishing between updates so I can filter out unimportant changes. So that I can prevent every cell from being updated.

Comment: setPrimitiveValue should still persist the values if you save its managedobjectcontext. I would just create a special setter method using this setprimitivevalue that is used by the background thread to make updates without triggering KVO.

Comment: Sounds good, this seems to work :). Its good to note it seems you need to save the context after setting it. Otherwise successive queries seem to act strange (they might not have the updated value). Another option (but a bit strange) is to move the property to another entity so that the controller doesn't see it as a change to the entity.